# Communicating with a class that's in use in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, class

I'm trying to communicate with a class that's already in use, something like this.
Assume "PROJECTNAME" as a namespace or the whole project

Class1:

```
Public Class Class1
 Dim Text1 As String
 Sub ChangeString(input as String)
  Text1 = String
 End Sub
 Sub Main()
  Do
   ' Code to prevent the Process stopping (Ignore This)
  Loop
 End Sub
End Class
```

Class 2:

```
Imports PROJECTNAME
Public Class Class2
 Dim ForeignClass1 As New Class1
 Dim ForeignClass2 As New Class1
 Sub Main()
  Do
   'Code to prevent the Process stopping(Ignore This)
  Loop
 End Sub
End Class
```

Class 3:

```
Imports PROJECTNAME
Public Class Class3
Dim CustomClass As New Class2
 Sub Main()
  'Code here to interact between "ForeignClass2" and "ForeignClass1"
 End Sub
End Class
```

The codes above is a concept that I'm trying to explain, not the actual code as it's a private code that I'm not suppose to expose. So what I want is to make "ForeignClass2" interact with "ForeignClass1" or make "ForeignClass1" interact with "ForeignClass2" without touching or making a new "Class1" array and just "ForeignClass1" and "ForeignClass2" only. How can I do that?

Comment: This is really just a general OOP question. Those two variables refer to objects like any other, so you would make those two objects "interact" just like you would any other two objects. You need to spend some time learning the principles of OOP and post back if and when you encounter a specific issue, rather than help with general concepts.

Comment: I also fail to see what this question has to do with arrays at all.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, sorry for tagging "array" but I tagged "array" because class1 was declared in class2 and class2 was declared in class3

Comment: That's not an array. When one type "has a" instance of another type, that's called composition. It's not a term that gets used all that much because it's a situation that occurs so much that it's just par for the course.